# Excel: Determining if Save or SaveAs is Used

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a version of the code for an add-in from the link below to check whether or not I have "Template" in the file name of any file I'm trying to save; however, I don't want a message box to appear if I click "Save As." Is there a way to determine what type of save is being executed? Thanks for the help!

Link: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-prog...e-w-addin.html

I've updated part of the Class Module as follows:

```
 Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) 
    Dim UserInput As String 
    If LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Name) Like "*template*" Then 
        UserInput = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to over-write the Template?", vbYesNo) 
        If UserInput <> vbYes Then 
            Cancel = True 
        End If 
    End If 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If the code is operating in a similar fashion to Excel's `Workbook_BeforeSave` event, the value of `SaveAsUI` will be `True` if the user is doing a Save As (i.e. if the SaveAs User Interface is being invoked, which therefore includes the first time a workbook is Saved), and `False` if they are just doing a normal Save.

Answer (score 0):

Using YowE3K's point you can shorten the code to just

```
If Not SaveAsUI Then Exit Sub
If LCase$(ActiveWorkbook.Name) Like "*template*" Then _
Cancel = (MsgBox("Are you sure you want to over-write the Template?", vbYesNo) = vbNo)
```

Comment: I guess my workbook `Things To Contemplate When Naming A File.xlsx` is going to be treated as a template? ;-P

Comment: Yep :) Possibly a RegExp or Like would better to filter out such matches.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. This will work if I save the code within template itself, but it doesn't work when I include it in the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

HI I used the same method as suggested by YowE3K  using the SaveAsUI.
Additionally make sure to store your templates as *.xltx or *xltm (for macro enabled) so when anyone opens them in the usual way it will create an unsaved document instead of actually opening the template file and allowing them to mess it by saving their changes.